# Finding functions where the increase over a random interval is Poisson distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, random, random-walk, random-functions

I'm trying to construct a type of function $f(t_1, t_2)$ that counts the number of deterministically simulated Poisson events between two points in time. We can use a single valued function g(t)=f(0,t) instead because $f(t_1, t_3) = f(t_1, t_2) + f(t_2, t_3)$ and consequently $f(s, t) = g(t) - g(s)$

The [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) for $f(t,t+l)$ for a random time t is the Poisson distribution PDF with an interval length l (by Poisson PDF I mean the Poisson PMF formula with real values). Formally:

$$
X_l(t) = f(t,t + l) = g(t+1) - g(t)
$$
$$
Pr(X_l \leq x) = CDF_{Pois}(x; \lambda = r \cdot l) = \frac{\Gamma(x+1, r \cdot l)}{\Gamma(x+ 1)}
$$
where:

- $l=intervalLength$
- $r=eventRate$
- $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function.
- $\Gamma(x,y)$ is the incomplete gamma function.

I also can't figure out how to compute $f$ from this, could I add anything to better define it? It seems like I could compute $f$ if I had a function for $g'$ that would to randomly go up and down while hovering above 0. $g''$ would also have to randomly go up and down. So we don't have to keep defining new functions with random dips and peaks perhaps it would hold that $g'(x) = g''(A_1x + A_2)\cdot B_1 + B_2$. In essence, maybe $g''$ is just $g'$ shifted and stretched, similar to $e^x$.

I'm using $f$ for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626844/how-do-i-sum-intervals-in-a-deterministic-poisson-process)  SO question.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I cleaned up the messy notation :>.

Comment: I don't understand. You're speaking about PMF and CDF, that are discrete functions, and then you talk about integrals and derivatives. They don't mix well.

Comment: @Xoff Sorry, I should have used the term [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) rather than PMF. I don't think CDF has to be a discrete function.

Comment: But Poisson is a discrete Law.

Comment: I think we can approximate the Poisson PMF with a function over the reals so we can do calculus with it. I think that's one way to derive the Poison CDF. I realize that there are restrictions on the derived functions, like needing to floor the inputs.

Comment: Please define `its real valued PMF approximation` (one can approximate a PDF by a PMF, but the other way round?).

Comment: @Did The real valued approximation for the Poisson distribution is the [Poisson PMF function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=l%5Ek%2F%28k%21%29+*+e%5E%28-l%29) with real values for k.

Comment: I fail to understand. If $P(X=x)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x!$ for every positive  real number $x$, then the total mass of the distribution of $X$ is $\gt1$ (and actually, infinite).

Comment: @Did It's not infinite, [the integral approaches 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+l%5Ek%2F%28k%21%29+*+e%5E%28-l%29+from+0+to+infinity). Maybe you're thinking of it as having discrete mass at every point, but the mass is the area under the curve.

Comment: It would help if you would write down clearly somewhere what you want $P(X\leqslant x)$ to be.

Comment: @Did I edited the question to add the formula for the Poisson CDF, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: [It seems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) that the formula you give for $P[X_\ell\leqslant x)$ is not nondecreasing with respect to $x$. If you use specific $\Gamma$ notations, please explain.

Comment: @Did why do you think it's not monotonic? [The plot looks monotonic for x >= 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%28x%2B1%2C2%29%2FGamma%28x%2B1%29)

Comment: Rrrright. So the distribution of each $X_\ell$ has a Dirac part at $0$ and a density part on $x\gt0$. What is your question already? There seems to be some random $X_\ell(t)$, not only $X_\ell$...

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the terms Diract part and density part, could you please define them or give a link? The question is can you help me find a computable function that fits the criteria of f. Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.